# Django request not defined

Tags: django, http

I am trying to implement an Http server and have the following line of code in my program

`if request.method == 'GET'`

I keep getting a NameError that request is not defined.

Here are my imports

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework import status
from people.models import People
from people.serializers import PeopleSerializer
```

I can not figure out why request is said to be not defined when it is a valid object in Http which i have imported.

full code snippet

```
@csrf_exempt
def people_detail(people, pk):
    try:
        people = People.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except People.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        people_serializer = PeopleSerializer(people)
        return JSONResponse(people_serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        people_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        people_serializer = PeopleSerializer(people, data = people_data)
        if people_serializer.is_valid():
            people_serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(people_serializer.data)
        return JSONResponse(people_serializer.errors,
        status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        people.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

people/views.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from people import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^people/$', views.people_list),
    url(r'people/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.people_detail),
]
```

people/peopleapi/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('people.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Where do you call `if request.method`?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov Inside view.py

Comment: Post the `views.py` here man. We're not telepaths.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov Now i have a different error stating that request has no attribute method

Comment: Post the code please.

Comment: @AndreyShipilov posted complete code snippet

Comment: Answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request` should be the first parameter for the view.

```
@csrf_exempt
def people_detail(request, pk):
...
```

Comment: This produces the following error : `people_detail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'people'`

Comment: What's in `urls.py`?

Comment: Well, why are you passing `people` to the view if it's not coming from the `url`?... I edited the answer.

Comment: I have 2 urls.py files though, should i post both ? one is inside people the other inside peopleapi